# Webapp to create filler text

Tags: webapp-rec

I need a webapp which creates arbitrary long text which I can use. Example given:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BlindTextGenerator](http://www.blindtextgenerator.com) looks quite nice. It offers more variantions of the content:

- Lorem ipsum, Cicero, Kafka, Pangram etc
- HTML-Tags
- Paragraphs

Answer (score 7):

[Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) is nice, but [**HTML Ipsum**](http://html-ipsum.com/) is better if you want to test the formatting too.

Sample output below:

---

## HTML Ipsum Presents

**Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique** senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. *Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.* Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, `commodo vitae`, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.

### Header Level 2

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
2. Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.

#### Header Level 3

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
- Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.

```
#header h1 a { 
    display: block; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 80px; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.lipsum.com/ works pretty good, and even works in other languages.

Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych, jak Aldus PageMaker

Comment: There is also a nice firefox plugin ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2064/ ) which is useful when filling a CMS with mocked up content.

Answer (score 2):

I just found [Fillerama](http://chrisvalleskey.com/fillerama/): "A lorem ipsum filler text generator, only with Futurama quotes."

It's fun and humorous, but perhaps not fit for professional presentations:

> It's just like the story of the
>   grasshopper and the octopus. All year
>   long, the grasshopper kept burying
>   acorns for winter, while the octopus
>   mooched off his girlfriend and watched
>   TV. But then the winter came, and the
>   grasshopper died, and the octopus ate
>   all his acorns. Also he got a race
>   car. Is any of this getting through to
>   you? Can we have Bender Burgers again?
>   Hey, what kinda party is this? There's
>   no booze and only one hooker.

Answer (score 1):

[www.lorem-ipsum.info/generator3](http://www.lorem-ipsum.info/generator3) looks promising.

Comment: i am absolutely afraid of clicking this anonymous "this" ...

Comment: @akira Why?  If you hover over the link you can see where it leads in your status bar (at the bottom)

Comment: i am using lynx right now, i can not see it.

Comment: A description of features, etc. would make a better answer than just a link. @akira: if the link text had said "Lorem Ipsum - Generator3", but the URL was `http://nevergonnagiveyouup.rickroll.bogustld`, you still would have been rick-rolled. The `=` key is your friend in `lynx`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: ... i think i know how to handle a browser. that was not the point of my first comment, neither was it the point of my 2nd comment.